# Had to search whether the substring are present in the strings or not

Tags: regex, string, list, scripting, tcl

I have a few substrings to search in the below following strings

```
These are the substrings "School, Students, Teachers, Classrooms"
```

Below are the strings here I have the search whether the above substrings are present in the below strings-

```
School_Name
Number_Of_Students
Number_Of_Teachers
Number_Of_Classrooms
```

I have tried in this way, here in the string I have Students, Teachers, Classrooms substrings present, but I'm not able to search it properly

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set list {School Students Teachers Classrooms}
set string "Number_Of_Students Number_Of_Teachers Number_Of_Classrooms"
if {"$string" in $list} {
puts "$string"
}
```

Can anyone help me out

Comment: Some homework required here?  Take a look at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm and https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M8 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator *only* does exact matching of a string against elements of a list. You probably want to use `lsearch` with a `string match`-style glob pattern; they're fairly easy to work with. Or maybe just `string match` and some `foreach` loops; I'm not sure what are the list of patterns and what are the list that is the search space.

```
# Added extra item to show what happens with multiple matches
set inputs {
    School_Name
    Number_Of_Students
    Number_Of_Teachers
    Number_Of_Classrooms
    Students_Per_School
}
set items {School Students Teachers Classrooms}
foreach input $inputs {
    foreach item $items {
        if {[string match *$item* $input]} {
            puts "found $item in $input"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You _can_ use a regular expression for this, but it's a bit overkill for such a simple case (and generating REs can be a bit pitfall-laden in general).